# Jquery RSS feed to HTML

Tags: jquery, html, json, parsing, rss

So I have an RSS feed that is printing correctly to the console with no errors.  I can see all the XML parsed in the console all nice and neat.  When I try to display in my HTML all I see is "undefined".  Here is my code:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url      : document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent('https://news.google.com/news?cf=all&hl=en&pz=1&ned=us&output=rss'),
    dataType : 'json',
    success  : function (data) {
        if (data.responseData.feed && data.responseData.feed.entries) {
            $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function (i, e) {
                console.log("------------------------");
                console.log("title      : " + e.title);
                console.log("author     : " + e.author);
                console.log("description: " + e.description);
                console.log("link: " + e.link);
            });
        }
        $('#rss-viewer')[0].innerHTML = data.innerHTML;
    }

});</script>  

<div id="rss-viewer"></div>
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: [This might help. I wrote it years ago. Works for the U.S. Army, since that's who I wrote it for ...](http://jsfiddle.net/Pp44S/)

Comment: oh and to be cross browser, you'll need to remove a couple lines i had in for debugging. basically just remove all the `console.log` lines as they are not IE compatible.

Comment: Also, `$('#rss-viewer')[0].innerHTML = ` would be better written in jQuery as `$('#rss-viewer').html('<inner html here>')

Comment: Try passing `e` to console.log directly and see if you're getting the data structure you think you're getting.

Comment: I actually got something when I did  'data = ("title      : " + e.title);' and then '$('#rss-viewer').html(data);' but it only gave me the last title.

Comment: Where is `data.innerHTML` supposed to come from? You said that data.responseData.feed.entries[i].title/author/description/link gave you the data you wanted. Why aren't you using them instead of innerHTML?

Answer (score 2):

There's no `data.innerHTML` on the return. `data` has the properties .`responseDate`, `.responseDetails`, and `.responseStatus`.

That aside, as aforementioned in a comment, I wrote [this plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/Pp44S/) years ago that makes reading RSS with jQuery extremely easy. I've recently posted it to get hub and made a few changes to it so it's even easier to use. Below, you'll see a simple example using your link and some very simple jQuery for creating elements from the returned feed and adding them to the DOM.

[Find On GitHub](https://github.com/JDMcKinstry/jQRSS)

Most basic use: `$.jQRSS('http://www.yourRSSurl.com/', { options }, function (newsFeed, feedEntries) { /* do work! */ })`

### Example:

```js
$.jQRSS('https://news.google.com/news?cf=all&hl=en&pz=1&ned=us&output=rss', { count: 8 }, function (feed, entries) {
 console.log('feed:', $(feed));
 $.each(entries, function(i) {
  if (this['content']) {
   var fieldset = $('<fieldset/>', { title: this.contentSnippet }).appendTo('body'),
   legend = $('<legend/>').appendTo(fieldset),
   $link = $('<a />', { href: this.link, html: this.title, target: '_blank' }).appendTo(legend),
   $date = $('<h5 />', { html: this.publishedDate, style: 'float:right;' }).appendTo(fieldset),
   $content = $(this.content).appendTo(fieldset);
   console.log('entry '+i+':', $(this));
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgit.com/JDMcKinstry/jQRSS/master/jQRSS.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why downvote? This is just an alternate way, and provides an `ease of use`. Take it or leave it.